# Multiple values to pass in a subreport SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Can I use the below expression to pass multiple value in a parameter in subreport?

```
=Join(LookupSet(1,1,Fields!Name.Value, "DatasetName")," / ")
```

Will the Join and LookupSet function work in prameter value expression?

Answer (score 0):

No your expression won't work. The **Available Values** for the Parameter are expecting a single record at a time.

I would create a parameter in the main report with the dataset as **DatasetName** with the Value of **Name**. You can set that to **Hidden** and don't need to use it.

Use that parameter to link to your sub report's parameter.

That should have the same functionality as what you want and would be faster that using the **JOIN/LOOKUPSET**.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the receiving parameter in the subreport is set to "allow multiple values", you should be able to pass in the lookupset array itself without needing the JOIN function at all.